# Htaccess deny access to json file

Tags: php, json, .htaccess

I'm using a json file as a DB in my project and I dont want users to be able to access it via url.
Here's what my .htaccess file looks like.

```
<Files "/users.json">
 deny from all
</Files>
```

But it doesn't work. "users.json" is stil accessable via direct url.

Comment: Could be you missed a bit or could be you are using Apache 2.4 (I would hope you are) Check out the DUP to see which

Comment: Or you could just place your file below the webroot.